# Making a Difference @ Open Source Projects

Tags: open-source, projects

Can I make a difference at an open source project?

I haven't gotten a degree or anything but I am really interested in computer science and I have most of the fundamentals down.

Is there a project I can make a difference at?  If not, any sites where I can further my knowledge and review the fundamentals (advanced concepts as well) of computer programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scour around [GitHub](http://www.github.com) for projects, there are plenty that could use some help.

At the very least, write tests for untested code and submit them back.  Even the littlest of contributions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Newcomers to an active Open Source project often feel like they are walking into a busy kitchen. A lot of different things going on and you feel like you are just in the way.

But often its not the case.

I can't point you to a specific project since i do not know your skillset or what you want to focus on.

Getting into an Open Source project can take time, its mostly based on the size of the project but usually its trying to see what is needed.

What i recommend is the same most people do, find a project that inspires you to make it better (even though its good to begin with), since that will make you want to stick around during the harder times.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Writing documentation and unit tests is good advice, but I'd suggest instead you find something you're particularly interested in, perhaps a piece of open source software you already use, and add a feature that you yourself want to use. It'll be more difficult, but it'll actually keep your interest and get you real world experience. Worst case your patch won't be accepted, but if it's a decent project they'll tell you why and what you need to do to make it acceptable.

Or, pick a small problem you want to see solved, and write an open source solution for it. The key is actually be interested in the problem you're solving.

Open source software is not magically high quality code; in fact it's not unusual to find sloppy code and practices. Don't be intimidated, jump in and give it a try. My first piece of open source still has a few users over 10 years later, but the code quality makes me cringe everytime I look at it.

Comment: I spent some good time righting code to fill in what is a gap in an open source projects. I never was allowed to have it included. Open source these days is just so closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net) and look for [projects that need help](http://sourceforge.net/people/).